# Where does UI setup code go?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have some code that sets up buttons in my view before the the program is presented.  Once the buttons are setup, there are no other changes to the UI for the rest of program execution.  Should this code go in viewDidLoad?

This is the type of code I'm referring to:

```
UIButton *buyerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buyerButton.frame = CGRectMake(leftSide, topSide+(c-1)*(buttonHeight+interButtonHeight), buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
[buyerButton setTitle:thisName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:buyerButton];
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "setup" you mean create (alloc/init), then you should rather do it in `awakeFromNib:` (if your view controller is loaded from a nib) or in `loadView` (if you create all of your GUI yourself).

If you actually mean setup (and the buttons are already added from the nib) then yes, you can do additional setup in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is the sort of code that's looking for a home:  UIButton *buyerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; [self.view addSubview:buyerButton];

Comment: You *can* put that in `viewDidLoad`, but as I said, `awakeFromNib:` or `loadView` would be a better choice.